# Google Script: Script to create calendar event runs without error but does nothing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var calendarName = "CALENDAR";
    var calTimeZone =  CalendarApp.openByName(calendarName).getTimeZone();
    var menuEntries = [ {name: "Update Calendar", functionName: "cal1"} ];
    ss.addMenu("Calendar", menuEntries);
    ss.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(calTimeZone);
}

function cal1() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var calendarName = "CALENDAR";
    var calTimeZone =  CalendarApp.openByName(calendarName).getTimeZone();
    var startRow = 3;
    var numRows = 100;
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 26);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("CALENDAR")[0];

    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        if (row[3] == "Add") {
            var title = row[24];  // Column with Title
            var desc = row[21];       // Column with Description
            var startdate = row[12];   //Column with Date
            var enddate = row[14];    //Column with Location
            cal.createEvent(title, startdate, enddate);  
        }
    } 
}
```

This is a simple script that's supposed to look through my spreadsheet and add it to my calendar if column 3 is "Add". The code runs without any error but when I check my calendar there is nothing there. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the logger I realised that the indexing starts from 0 (column C = row[2], not row[3]). It's a silly mistake, and as much as I'd like to delete this question away I thought it would be good to put this out there in case someone does the same thing.